# How would I populate a DropDownList's value and text fields with information in a DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, datatable

How would I populate a `DropDownList's` value and text fields with information in a DataTable?

**Example DataTable**

```
Employees : EmployeeID, Name
```

I tried...

```
EmployeeDropDownList.DataTextField = Employees.NameColumn
EmployeeDropDownList.DataValueField = Employees.EmployeeIDColumn
EmployeeDropDownList.DataBind()
```

The two assignment lines are invalid though because it's not the correct datatype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
EmployeeDropDownList.DataSource=Employees.DefaultView
EmployeeDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name"
EmployeeDropDownList.DataValueField = "EmployeeID"
EmployeeDropDownList.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
EmployeeDropDownList.DataTextField = "NameColumn"

EmployeeDropDownList.DataValueField = "EmployeeIDColumn"
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
EmployeeDropDownList.DataTextField = "NameColumn"
EmployeeDropDownList.DataValueField = "EmployeeIDColumn"
```

The `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` accept string values only. Whereas, in your code you had given DataColumn type as those property's values.